# Оттенки смыслов

Tags: семантика, лексика

Недавно я рассердилась на одного участника форума (не Сети Знаний). Наверное он решил, что я обиделась. Но я так не думаю. А вот вопрос.

Чем отличаются смыслы этих слов - **обидеться** и **рассердится**?  Я чувствую, что это разные слова, но не уверена, что смогу четко сформулировать эту разницу.

Comment: оттенки _**смыслов**_?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Никогда бы не подумал, что эти слова можно смешать.
Обижается тот, кому нанесли обиду, чаще - личную, и обычно это более слабый, зависимый, максимум - равный. Вы бы на кошку обиделись? На комаров?

Ну а сердиться можно на кого угодно. Даже на новорожденного, который уж точно никаких направленных действий по отношению к вам не совершал.

Comment: Да, пожалуй, согласна. Кстати, как-то я видела такую мамашу, которая ругала ребенка в коляске ... сволочью! На мое недоумение  она сказала: "Вот будут у Вас дети - поймете".  
Появился. Не поняла! Невозможно так отнестись к ребенку!

Answer (score 3):

Обидеться - чувствовать обиду,т.е. горечь, досаду, вызванные несправедливым, оскорбительным отношением к себе.

Сердиться - испытывать раздражение, гнев на кого-либо,   синонимы -    гневаться, злиться, серчать. И это не обязательно связано с обидой.

Правда, в словаре синонимов они в одном ряду, но синонимы - похожие слова, а не тождественные(обидеться, оскорбиться, жаловаться, негодовать, роптать, претендовать на что, сердиться, быть в обиде, задеваться, дуться, ударяться в амбицию, надувать губы, быть в претензии, расстраиваться, входить в амбицию, ущемляться, притесняться, дуться как мышь на крупу; частичн.: оскорбиться, огорчиться). Похожесть в негативных эмоциях.

Answer (score 0):

Обидеться - чувственное, практически нейтральное по отношению к действию. Рассердиться - действенное, побудительное к поступку.